# Webrtc peer to peer screen sharing

Tags: node.js, webrtc, easyrtc

I am new to webrtc. is it possible to share screen from peer to peer?

I am new to easyrtc. is it possible to share screen from peer to peer?

I tried screen share demo example of easyrtc but i got **"LocalMediaError"** and i installed all required plugins also.
please let me know if it possible

Comment: I tried with peer js, If someone need to check. [link to screen sharing demo](https://github.com/Abhi5h3k/WebRTC-PeerJs-Demo)

Answer (score 0):

*WebRTC* is a Peer-To-Peer service where each peer is a browser, with all the constraints that it implies.

So as you've seen with *easyRTC*, the only way to get desktop screen sharing would be to use a browser extension.

**Edit:** [Here](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/Pluginfree-Screen-Sharing/#47124111559268236) is the example I came across.

Comment: i tried easyrtc demo example .   https://demo.easyrtc.com/demos/demo_screen_send.html  https://demo.easyrtc.com/demos/demo_screen_receive.html                    i got LocalMedia Error

Comment: can you provide exact link for easyrtc screensharing.

Comment: Sure, I edited the answer. I haven't tried easyrtc but the example I linked above also requires a plugin.

Comment: is it possible to share screen to particular user

Comment: yes, and only to that particular user, as it's P2P.

Comment: thank you for your suggestions. I want to share screen for particular user that mean i have login form and user give the credenticilas. Then i want share screen to particular user based on texfield value. is it possible in webrtc.

Comment: Yes, this process of establishing contact between two particular users is called signaling, read more here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Signaling_and_video_calling

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a plugin, you can simply use navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia and easyrtc.register3rdPartyLocalMediaStream.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getDisplayMedia

Example:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({video: true}).then(function (stream) {
    easyrtc.register3rdPartyLocalMediaStream(stream, 'screen:1');

    // Then to add to existing connection
    easyrtc.addStreamToCall(easyrtcId, 'screen:1', function (caller, streamName) {

    });
})
```

https://github.com/open-easyrtc/open-easyrtc/issues/42